# Garbage-collect a lock once no threads are asking for it

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, thread-safety

I have a function that must never be called with the same value simultaneously from two threads. To enforce this, I have a `defaultdict` that spawns new `threading.Lock`s for a given key. Thus, my code looks similar to this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import threading

lock_dict = defaultdict(threading.Lock)
def f(x):
    with lock_dict[x]:
        print "Locked for value x"
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to *safely* delete the lock from the defaultdict once its no longer needed. Without doing this, my program has a memory leak that becomes noticeable when `f` is called with many different values of x.

I cannot simply `del lock_dict[x]` at the end of f, because in the scenario that another thread is waiting for the lock, then the second thread will lock a lock that's no longer associated with lock_dict[x], and thus two threads could end up simultaneously calling `f` with the same value of x.

Comment: Are you sure that it's safe to use `defaultdict` there? Seems like you have a potential race condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use a different approach:

```
fcond = threading.Condition()
fargs = set()

def f(x):
    with fcond:
        while x in fargs:
            fcond.wait()
        fargs.add(x)  # this thread has exclusive rights to use `x`

    # do useful stuff with x
    # any other thread trying to call f(x) will
    # block in the .wait above()

    with fcond:
        fargs.remove(x)      # we're done with x
        fcond.notify_all()   # let blocked threads (if any) proceed
```

Conditions have a learning curve, but once it's climbed they make it much easier to write correct thread-safe, race-free code.

### Thread safety of the original code

@JimMischel asked in a comment whether the orignal's use of `defaultdict` was subject to races.  Good question!

The answer is - alas - "you'll have to stare at your specific Python's implementation".

Assuming the CPython implementation:  if *any* of the code invoked by `defaultdict` to supply a default invokes Python code, or C code that releases the GIL (global interpreter lock), then 2 (or more) threads could "simultaneously" invoke `withlock_dict[x]` with the same `x` not already in the dict, and:

1. Thread 1 sees that `x` isn't in the dict, gets a lock, then loses its timeslice (before setting `x` in the dict).
2. Thread 2 sees that `x` isn't in the dict, and also gets a lock.
3. One of those thread's locks ends up in the dict, but both threads execute `f(x)`.

Staring at the source for 3.4.0a4+ (the current development head), `defaultdict` and `threading.Lock` are both implemented by C code that doesn't release the GIL.  I don't recall whether earlier versions did or didn't, at various times, implement all or parts of `defaultdict` or `threading.Lock` in Python.

My suggested alternative code is full of stuff implemented in Python (all `threading.Condition` methods), but is race-free by design - even if you're using an old version of Python with sets also implemented in Python (the set is only accessed under the protection of the condition variable's lock).

### One lock per argument

Without conditions, this seems to be much harder.  In the original approach, I believe you need to keep a count of threads wanting to use `x`, and you need a lock to protect those counts and to protect the dictionary.  The best code I've come up with for that is so long-winded that it seems sanest to put it in a context manager.  To use, create an argument locker per function that needs it:

```
farglocker = ArgLocker() # for function `f()`
```

and then the body of `f()` can be coded simply:

```
def f(x):
    with farglocker(x):
        # only one thread at a time can run with argument `x`
```

Of course the condition approach could also be wrapped in a context manager.  Here's the code:

```
import threading

class ArgLocker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.xs = dict() # maps x to (lock, count) pair
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __call__(self, x):
        return AllMine(self.xs, self.lock, x)

class AllMine:
    def __init__(self, xs, lock, x):
        self.xs = xs
        self.lock = lock
        self.x = x

    def __enter__(self):
        x = self.x
        with self.lock:
            xlock = self.xs.get(x)
            if xlock is None:
                xlock = threading.Lock()
                xlock.acquire()
                count = 0
            else:
                xlock, count = xlock
            self.xs[x] = xlock, count + 1

        if count: # x was already known - wait for it
            xlock.acquire()
        assert xlock.locked

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        x = self.x
        with self.lock:
            xlock, count = self.xs[x]
            assert xlock.locked
            assert count > 0
            count -= 1
            if count:
                self.xs[x] = xlock, count
            else:
                del self.xs[x]
            xlock.release()
```

So which way is better?  Using conditions ;-)  That way is "almost obviously correct", but the lock-per-argument (LPA) approach is a bit of a head-scratcher.  The LPA approach does have the advantage that when a thread is done with `x`, the *only* threads allowed to proceed are those wanting to use the same `x`; using conditions, the `.notify_all()` wakes all threads blocked waiting on *any* argument.  But unless there's very heavy contention among threads trying to use the same arguments, this isn't going to matter much:  using conditions, the threads woken up that aren't waiting on `x` stay awake only long enough to see that `x in fargs` is true, and then immediately block (`.wait()`) again.